# Dropbox login View sample code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am following the Dropbox [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/tutorial/ios) and it gives me this code:

```
- (IBAction)pressLink {
[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:YOUR_ROOT_CONTROLLER];
}
```

This is supposed to be linked to a button and it should show the login screen for dropbox, i changed the `YOUR_ROOT_CONTROLLER` section of code to `settings`, which is the view that holds the button that is being pressed. But when i press the button, nothing happens. It says `ROOT`, so is it asking for my actual `initial` view controller?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)pressLink
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
SettingsViewController * settings = (SettingsViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"];
[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:settings];
}
```

This is what i changed the button method to, because with just `YOUR_ROOT_CONTROLLER` there, it was giving me an error, but now, as i said it does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated! THanks

Comment: Have you tried logging both storyboard and settings to se if either is nil?

Comment: Are you saying that settings is the controller where you have the above code? Is so, then you shouldn't be instantiating a new instance of SettingsViewController, you should just pass self to linkFromController:

Comment: @rdelmar your comment worked perfect, if you like, you could post it as an answer and ill check mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that settings is the controller where you have the above code, then you shouldn't be instantiating a new instance of SettingsViewController. You should just pass self to linkFromController: